# Multiple parameters in Replace SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I am using SQL Server 2016. I have a column `A` that has values such as `C20.1` and `C20.2`. I just want to remove the postfix values (`.1` and `.2`) and keep `C20` only.

```
Column A
---------
C20
C20.1
C20.2
```

Output should be like this:

```
Column B
--------
C20
C20
C20
```

I tried this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (ColumnA, '.1', '.2', '')
```

but this query throws an error when I pass 4 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring()`

```
select substring(columnA,0,4)
from table
```

Comment: The best expression is `left(columnA, 4)`.

Answer (score 2):

We could phrase your requirement as saying that you want to retain the input string up, but not including, the first dot, or if not dot be present, then retain the entire string.  This gives us:

```sql
SELECT
    val,
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.', val) > 0
         THEN SUBSTRING(val, 1, CHARINDEX('.', val) - 1)
         ELSE val END AS val_out
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo